# detecting tenons on plugs with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, angle, detect

i'm currently working on a project that requires me to find the angles between tenons on some plugs . from what i have seen it seems like using opencv for this type of project is the way to go.

what i want to know is of there is a built in function in opencv that can do that or if there are a series of functions that will enable me to find the angles between the tenons . in the pictures below you can see some examples of the plugs , the teeth circled are the tenons .

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WEl6lDuw4QhqOFWVdC5T0YgAfBi753uv?usp=sharing

the angles of the tenons need to be calculated in relation to the biggest tennon .

Comment: can you point out what's a "tenon" here? keep the untouched source images, but maybe add another with the desired features circled. it might be a good idea to take pictures with more (optical) zoom, so the object uses more of the camera's resolution

Comment: Hi , i circled the tenons in the pictures that are on the drive .

Comment: Getting closer, or using a longer lens, and focussing would make life easier.

Comment: currently i'm not at home so i'm not near the plugs but when i get home i will upload better pictures .

Comment: i uploaded more pictures with better quality

Comment: I'd recommend *not* getting too close because those features look like they are on the outside of the cylinder and more to the middle of it than the rim... so the closer you get, the more they are occluded by the cylinder.

Comment: these things could be tricky to work out of the picture. play with lighting (use a flashlight/torch/...) and see if you can cause some contrast between a tenon and whatever's under/behind it. localization of these features might involve (in any order) thresholding, finding circles/contours that are circular, looking for things relative to those "landmarks", ...